# Startup script failed execution on a google instance

Tags: python, pip, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I have a startup script that I use to install python and import files from a google storage bucket to the VM. When I keep my startup script as follows:

```
‘#! /bin/bash
gsutil cp gs://bucket/file /homedirectory'
```

It executes successfully. But when I add

```
'curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py"
python get-pip.py --user
pip install pandas --user
pip install scipy --user
pip install scikit-learn --user
pip install sklearn —user
pip install matplotlib --user'
```

to the script, it doesn't execute the script. My full command is as follows

```
gcloud compute instances create instance2  \
--metadata startup-script='#! /bin/bash
curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py"
python get-pip.py --user
pip install pandas --user
pip install scipy --user
pip install scikit-learn --user
pip install sklearn —user
pip install matplotlib --user
gsutil cp gs://bucket/file /homedirectory'
```

Apologies I started using starting scripts recently and am still unfamiliar with them.

Answer (score 0):

You have an [em dash](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm) on this line:

```
pip install sklearn —user
```

It should be:

```
pip install sklearn --user
```

Otherwise, this will cause an exception when trying to run the startup script like so:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/google_metadata_script_runner", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('google-compute-engine==2.8.3', 'console_scripts', 'google_metadata_script_runner')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_scripts/script_manager.py", line 109, in main
    debug=bool(options.debug))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_scripts/script_manager.py", line 69, in __init__
    self._RunScripts(run_dir=run_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_scripts/script_manager.py", line 80, in _RunScripts
    script_dict = self.retriever.GetScripts(dest_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_scripts/script_retriever.py", line 213, in GetScripts
    return (self._GetAttributeScripts(instance_data, dest_dir) or
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_scripts/script_retriever.py", line 179, in _GetAttributeScripts
    dest.write(metadata_value.lstrip())
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2014' in position 201: ordinal not in range(128)
```

You can see the logs for the startup script by navigating to:

[Compute Engine](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances) > (Your Instance Name) > Logs > Serial port 1 (console)

Comment: Also to debug a startup script it's usually handy to re-run it on the instance: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#rerunthescript

Comment: Hi so thanks everyone. The em dash I actually removed when I copied the command on the cloud shell. When I rerun the script it works. But otherwise it just works for the first 3-4 times i try running the above command.